# aurelia - computedFrom

Tags: aurelia

I have the following:

```
.ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate', (config) => { config.computedFrom(['baseContent.ValidFromDate', 'baseContent.ValidFromTime', 'baseContent.ValidToDate', 'baseContent.ValidToTime']) })
                        .if(() => {
                            return this.baseContent.ValidFromDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidFromTime !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToTime !== null })
                            .passes( () => { return this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime) < this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidToDate, this.baseContent.ValidToTime) })
                            .withMessage('< Valid To')
                        .endIf()
```

I believed that  `config.computedFrom(['baseContent.ValidFromDate', 'baseContent.ValidFromTime', 'baseContent.ValidToDate', 'baseContent.ValidToTime'])` - meant that if one of these values changed it would re-run the validation? However it only does this on `'baseContent.ValidFromDate'`, what am I missing / not understanding?

**UPDATE**

Seems the issue is to do with computedFrom doesn't support paths, don't really know another way round this barring adding this validation to the four items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was added last week (aurelia-binding 1.0.0-beta.1.3.0). See https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/149

Syntax when used as a decorator is:

```
@computedFrom('obj.firstName', 'obj.lastName')
```

Comment: Thanks @Sylvain, Ill look at updating my project

Comment: do you know, how I can find out if there is any breaking changes? I can't seem to locate their release notes

Comment: They post a blog entry with each release at http://blog.durandal.io/, the one for that release is here http://blog.durandal.io/2016/03/23/aurelia-babel-6-and-jspm-update/, that's how I learned about the new `computedFrom` feature (I don't actually use it).

Comment: Hello @Sylvain, I've updated aurelia-binding to the latest version. However the validation is still not working:  config.computedFrom(['baseContent.ValidFromDate', 'baseContent.ValidFromTime', 'baseContent.ValidToDate', 'baseContent.ValidToTime']) }) only doing the if statement on .ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate'

Comment: @ClareBarrington did you first try `@computedFrom` as a decorator as described in the documentation? I mean outside validation?

Comment: Hello @Sylvain, I've been told: "aurelia bindings can't bind normally to Date objects" so thinking of another way to do this.

Comment: @ClareBarrington You might be experiencing [this](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/269), if that's the case you can use the provided workaround or use a value converter to convert your date to a string.